# Переформатрирование даты в R

Tags: дата, r

Имея в R даты в следующем формате:

```
Jan 2007
Feb 2007
Mar 2007
```

как можно их переформатировать к такому виду:

```
2007-01-01
2007-02-01
2007-03-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вопросе содержится неточность. Более точная формулировка: имеются некий набор строк в определённом формате (аббревиатура месяца на английском и год), которые необходимо преобразовать во внутреннее представление даты в R.

Пакет `stringi` содержит функцию `stri_datetime_parse`.

```
x <- c("Jan 2007", "Feb 2007", "Mar 2007")
as.Date(stringi::stri_datetime_parse(x, "LLL yyyy", locale = "en_US"))
#> [1] "2007-01-04" "2007-02-04" "2007-03-04"
```

- `yyyy` - формат года (четырехзначный)
- `LLL` - формат месяца (аббревиатура)

Подробнее о формате парсинга см. справку к функции `stri_datetime_parse`. Также таблица приведена здесь: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

Отдельно указываем локаль, т.к. аббревиатуры месяцев отличаются в разных локалях. Посмотреть зависимую от локали информацию можно с помощью функции `stri_datetime_symbols` из того же пакета. Например, для локали `en_US`:

```
stringi::stri_datetime_symbols(locale = "en_US")
#> $Month
#>  [1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"      
#>  [6] "June"      "July"      "August"    "September" "October"  
#> [11] "November"  "December" 
#> 
#> $Weekday
#> [1] "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
#> [7] "Saturday" 
#> 
#> $Quarter
#> [1] "1st quarter" "2nd quarter" "3rd quarter" "4th quarter"
#> 
#> $AmPm
#> [1] "AM" "PM"
#> 
#> $Era
#> [1] "Before Christ" "Anno Domini"
```

Comment: Спасибо ВАм огромное!!!